# why background image is not applied in my react native project

Tags: css, react-native

In-app folder, I have two folder screens and assets  I am giving the correct path but the background image is not applied to the emulator.

[image]

Comment: Please do not use screenshots of your code and error messages. Screenshots are hard to read on mobile devices, they cannot be searched and none of us can copy, paste and run an image. Read  


[**Why may I not upload images of code**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557) 
on SO when asking a question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put your image tag between view tags so that react native will render you image on your emulator, for example :

In your `App`

```
const App = (props) => {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container} >
      <Image style= { styles.backgroundImage } source=>
      </Image>
      <View style={styles.logoContainer}>
        <Text style={styles.logoText}>
          Hello
        </Text>
        <Text style={styles.logoDescription}>
         Hello world
        </Text>
      </View>
    </View>
  );
}
```

You may wanna add some `styles` to it

```
backgroundImage:{
    position: 'absolute',
    top: 0,
    left: 0,
    bottom: 0,
    right: 0,
    opacity: 0.3
},
```

And in your case, you are using `ImageBackground` it should be something like this :

```
const App = (props) => {
  return (
    <View style = { styles.container } >
    <ImageBackground  style= { styles.backgroundImage } source= >

      <View style= { styles.logoContainer }>
        <Text style = { styles.logoText }>
          Hello
        </Text>
        <Text style = { styles.logoDescription }>
          Hello world
        </Text>

      </View>
      </ImageBackground>
    </View>
  );
}
```

Comment: i have just one element is it necessary to wrap in backgrounImage?

Comment: Dont consider how many elements you have got ,image tag or background image tag is needed

Answer (score 1):

Wrap your imageBackground with View:

```
    <View style={styles.imgWrap}>
      <ImageBackground 
        source={require('assets/img/avatar-placeholder.png')} 
        style={styles.img} 
      />
    </View>
```

and then add some styles:

```
 const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  imgWrap: {
    width: 100,
    height: 100,
    overflow: 'hidden',
    borderRadius: 50,
  },
  img: {
    flex: 1,
    resizeMode: "contain",
    justifyContent: "center"
  }
})
```

Comment: I didnt notice that u want full screen so then use this:

imgWrap: {
    flex: 1,
  },
  img: {
    flex: 1,
    resizeMode: "cover",
  }